# Node.js - javascript calling functions from javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a Express/NodeJs project. I am new to Express/NodeJs, I am trying to import airportQuery.js into DistanceFormula.js. I am trying to directly import airportQuery.js from DistanceFormula.js. Im trying to call getAirports and return the answer to DistanceFormula.js. I not sure if I have to use the node routing or if i'm doing it correctly.

File Stucture:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi8Sc.png)

DistanceFormula.JS

```
import {getAirports} from "./api/airportQuery";
console.log(getAirports('3c675a'));
```

AirportQuery.js

```
async function getAirports(planeIcao) {
        let airport = {
            arrival: "",
            destination: ""
        };
        const airport_url = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/flights/aircraft?icao24=' + planeIcao + '&begin=1517184000&end=1517270400';
        const response = await fetch(airport_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[0].estArrivalAirport);
        airport.arrival = data[0].estArrivalAirport;
        console.log(data[0].estDepartureAirport);
        airport.destination = data[0].estDepartureAirport;
        return airport
    }
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

export {getAirports};
```

ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use modules in node.js, you have to do the following:

1. Be running a version of nodejs that supports ESM modules (v8.5+).
2. Run with this command line flag: `node --experimental-modules`
3. Name your file with an .mjs file extension OR [specify it as a module in package.json](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_package_json_code_code_type_code_field)

See the [relevant documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) for more info.

This is true not only for the top level file you `import`, but if it also uses `import`, then the same rules above have to apply to it too.

---

Note, that once you get your modules to load properly, you will then have a problem with this line of code because `getAirports()` returns promise, not a value.  All `async` functions return a promise, always.  The `return` value in the function will become the resolved value of the returned promise.  That's how `async` functions work.  So, change this:

```
console.log(getAirports('3c675a'));
```

To this:

```
getAirports('3c675a').then(result=> {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: @jamo1909 - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.