# I can't use es6 syntax to run a script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I want to run a js script, that require some ts, and js file in my node project.
I use this command node --experimental-modules src/scripts/myScript.js
In my myScript.js i can't use import syntax only require is working. So i tend to use require only.
But myScript.js is using multiple ts and js files that are using import syntax.
Here is the error i got:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/*****/Desktop/*****/l****/src/scripts/myScript.js:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

Comment: as far as I know, neither `import` nor typescript are supported by node. You'll need some sort of transpilation step.

Comment: Here already answered to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: Explanation here: [Using import in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775491/node-js-javascript-calling-functions-from-javascript-file/58775856#58775856)

Comment: run the script with npx ts-node was the solution